# UDP Client server works on same computer but not over lan

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a simple application that sends continuous UDP packets from a server to a client.  Everything works well if the server app and client app are on the same computer but the minute I move the client to another computer in the LAN it stops working with a message
"the requested address is not valid in its context".  I really don't understand why this is happening.
Here is the server code:

```
public void SendData()
{
    udpClient = new UdpClient();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i++)
    {
        dataBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt16(dataValues[i]));
    }

    udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

    try
    {
        udpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);

        udpClient.Send(dataBytes, dataBytes.Length);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

On the client machine here is the code:

```
private void receive()
{
            try
            {
                udpClient = new UdpClient();

                udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

                udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

                int port = Convert.ToInt32("13064");
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.107");

                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
                socket = new UdpClient(localEndPoint);

                udpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);

                socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceivedDataCallback), socket);                   
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!socketConnected)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
}

private void ReceivedDataCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    try
    {
        socketConnected = true;

        clientSocket = AR.AsyncState as UdpClient;

        var port = Convert.ToInt32("13064");
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.107");

        IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        nums = clientSocket.EndReceive(AR, ref source);

        OutputRemoteSamples();

        clientSocket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceivedDataCallback), clientSocket);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions
Tom

Comment: Both cases are true.  IOne question...how does the server get the address of the client?  Seems maybe I am missing this?

Comment: Generally a server would bind to a port, then reply to incoming packets. So calling `.Connect` doesn't make much sense. Not that connect makes much sense for UDP in general. It's only use is to implicitly provide a destination endpoint.

Comment: `int port = Convert.ToInt32("13064");` what's that about, why not `int port = 13064;`